# How do I parse a TOML file with a table at the top level into a Rust structure?

Tags: rust, serde, toml

For example:

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate toml;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Entry {
    foo: String,
    bar: String,
}

let toml_string = r#"
  [[entry]]
  foo = "a0"
  bar = "b0"

  [[entry]]
  foo = "a1"
  bar = "b1"
  "#;
let config: toml::value::Table<Entry> = toml::from_str(&toml_string)?;
```

However, this does not work and throws an error about unexpected type argument for `Table`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Printing the arbitrary parsed value shows you what structure you have:

```
let config: toml::Value = toml::from_str(&toml_string)?;
println!("{:?}", config)
```

The reformatted output shows that you have a table with a single key `entry` which is an array of tables with the keys `foo` and `bar`:

```
Table({
  "entry": Array([
    Table({
      "bar": String("b0"),
      "foo": String("a0")
    }),
    Table({
      "bar": String("b1"),
      "foo": String("a1")
    })
  ])
})
```

When deserializing, you need to match this structure:

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Outer {
    entry: Vec<Entry>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Entry {
    foo: String,
    bar: String,
}
```

```
let config: Outer = toml::from_str(&toml_string)?;
```

Comment: Didn't know that I have to add a surrounding type. Thanks for your help!